# terraformを使ってGCPのVMインスタンスに静的IPを予約する

Tags: google-cloud

terraformを使ってGCPのVMインスタンスの作成をしております。terraformのtfファイルの設定は公式ページを読んで設定しておりますが、VMインスタンスに静的なグローバルIPアドレスを予約する方法（設定する方法）がわかりませんでした。
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_global_address.html
そもそもグローバルIPはエフェメラルのみでしか設定できないのかどうかという部分でも定かではありません。

```
resource "google_compute_global_address" "default" {
  ip_version = "IPV4"
  name = "global-appserver-ip"
}
```

この設定でエフェメラルのグローバルIPアドレスを付与することはできましたが、静的なグローバルIPアドレスの設定方法がわかりませんでした。

もしかしたらインターフェイスがすでに間違っているのかもしれません。
もしここら辺りの設定に詳しい方おりましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: 本家SOに同様の質問があり、回答が付いているようです。これを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。 https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947257/10216107

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちら参考にいたします。

Comment: 上手く行かなければ結果やエラーなどを追記していただき、もし上手く行ったらその旨コメントなどしていただけると（今後同様の質問をした方のためにも）助かります。